# Is it possible to reuse default message in FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to reuse the default message that validator gives and attach some data to it? For instance, MaxLength validator returns message like "The length of < FieldName > must be n characters or fewer. You entered m characters". What I need is to get something like "Id 123456: < default validator message >". WithMessage just overrides the whole message, and copy-pasting output for each validator is nonsense.

Comment: have you tried resource files? How about an "Messages" class with static text that you can use in the with message method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom MessageBuilder to do this. This is an advanced feature of the library that I haven't had a chance to document yet, but it allows you to intercept the message as it's being generated, and tweak it.

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> WrapDefaultMessage<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, string template) {
        return ruleBuilder.Configure(rule => {
            // A rule can only have a single message builder.
            // If it already has one, cache it and call it from within our new one below
            // (essentially chaining them together).
            var originalMessageBuilder = rule.MessageBuilder;

            rule.MessageBuilder = context => {
                // Generate the default message.
                string message = originalMessageBuilder?.Invoke(context) ?? context.GetDefaultMessage();

                // Now add that message *back* into the message formatter as a custom placeholder value.
                context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("DefaultMessage", message);

                // Now construct new message using the supplied template,
                // which allows the new DefaultMessage placeholder to be used.
                return context.MessageFormatter.BuildMessage(template);
            };
        });
    }
}
```

...which you can then use like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WrapDefaultMessage("ID 12345 {DefaultMessage}");
```

...if your ID '12345' comes from another property on the object, then you could modify the code to take a callback instead of a string which would allow you to access this inside the message:

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    // Note that the parameter is now a Func<T, string> instead of a string.
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> WrapDefaultMessage<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, Func<T, string> templateBuilder) {
        return ruleBuilder.Configure(rule => {
            // A rule can only have a single message builder.
            // If it already has one, cache it and call it from within our new one below
            // (essentially chaining them together).
            var originalMessageBuilder = rule.MessageBuilder;

            rule.MessageBuilder = context => {
                // Generate the default message.
                string message = originalMessageBuilder?.Invoke(context) ?? context.GetDefaultMessage();

                // Now add that message *back* into the message formatter as a custom placeholder value.
                context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("DefaultMessage", message);

                // Now construct new message using the supplied template,
                // which allows the new DefaultMessage placeholder to be used.
                return context.MessageFormatter.BuildMessage(templateBuilder((T)context.InstanceToValidate));
            };
        });
    }
}
```

...which you can then use like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WrapDefaultMessage(x => $"Id {x.Id} {{DefaultMessage}}");
```

(Note that you must double-escape the placeholder brackets when used inside an interpolated string like this).